# Remove dots before @ sign in email address

Tags: python

I have this string:

```
no.reply.random@gmail.com
```

How could I have the dots before the @ sign removed?

The expected output would look like this:

```
noreplyrandom@gmail.com
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Split the string at the `'@'`, replace the dots in the first part, put everything back together.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split` and `replace` like so:

```
string = `no.reply.random@gmail.com`
stringList = string.split()
stringList[0] = stringList[0].replace(".","")
new = "@".join(stringList)
```

Output:

```
noreplyrandom@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s='no.reply.random@gmail.com'
at=s.index('@')
output=s[:at].replace('.','')+s[at:]
print(output)
```